# Flux - parallel flatMap with webclient - limit to fixed batched rate

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflux, project-reactor, spring-webclient

The code I have is this:

```
return Flux.fromIterable(new Generator()).log()
        .flatMap(
            s ->
                webClient
                    .head()
                    .uri(
                        MessageFormat.format(
                            "/my-{2,number,#00}.xml",
                            channel, timestamp, s))
                    .exchangeToMono(r -> Mono.just(r.statusCode()))
                    .filter(HttpStatus::is2xxSuccessful)
                    .map(r -> s),
            6)  //only request 6 segments in parallel via webClient
        .take(6) //we need only 6 200 OK responses
        .sort();
```

It just requests `HEAD`, until first 6 requests are successful.

Parallelization works here, but the problem is that after 1 of the requests is complete, it immediatley triggers next request (to maintain parallelization level of 6). What I need here is to have parallelization level of 6, but in batches. So - trigger 6 requests, wait until all complete, trigger again 6 requests ...

This is the output of the `log()` above:

```
: | request(6)
: | onNext(7)
: | onNext(17)
: | onNext(27)
: | onNext(37)
: | onNext(47)
: | onNext(57)
: | request(1) <---- from here NOT OK; wait until all complete and request(6)
: | onNext(8)
: | request(1)
: | onNext(18)
: | request(1)
: | onNext(28)
: | request(1)
: | onNext(38)
: | request(1)
: | onNext(48)
: | request(1)
: | onNext(58)
: | cancel()
```

**UPDATE**

this is what I tried with the buffer:

```
return Flux.fromIterable(new Generator())
        .buffer(6)
        .flatMap(Flux::fromIterable)
        .log()
        .flatMap(
            s ->
                webClient
                    .head()
                    .uri(
                        MessageFormat.format(
                            "/my-{2,number,#00}.xml",
                            channel, timestamp, s))
                    .exchangeToMono(r -> Mono.just(r.statusCode()))
                    .filter(HttpStatus::is2xxSuccessful)
                    .map(r -> s),
            6)  //only request 6 segments in parallel via webClient
        .take(6)
        .sort();
```

Comment: Look into using `buffer` Before doing your requests

Comment: @Toerktumlare tries adding `.buffer(6).flatMap(Flux::fromIterable)` before `webClient` part. Seems it still polls 6 and from there 1 by 1 (according to the log). Do you have some example how this should work in batches of 6?

Comment: What do you mean by ”1 by 1”?

Comment: @Toerktumlare the log is still the same: first I get `request(6)` and then from there it goes 1 by 1 = `request(1)` and then `request(1)` and then `request(1)`...

Comment: please dont explain what you have done in comments, update your question with what you have tried in code. We can guess what your code looks like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, It seems I have the code that works. Here I use `window`:

```
return Flux.fromIterable(new Generator())
        .window(6) //group 1,2,3,4,5,6,7... into [0,1,2,3,4,5],[6,7..,11],[12,..,17]
        .log()
        .flatMap(
            s -> s.log().flatMap(x -> webClient
                .head()
                .uri(
                    MessageFormat.format(
                        "/my-{2,number,#00}.xml",
                        channel, timestamp, x))
                .exchangeToMono(r -> Mono.just(r.statusCode()))
                .filter(HttpStatus::is2xxSuccessful)
                .map(r -> x), 6), 1)  //1 means take only 1 array ([0,1,2,3,4,5]). 6 means take in parallel all from array (0,1,2,3,4,5)
        .take(6, true) //pass through only 6 elements (cancel afterwards)
        .sort();
```